# What is the best practice to store the image data in firestore?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For my application, I'm storing some data in the firestore database. The data include images. Here, I'm storing Google drive URL of the images and fetching the image with the glide.  Is this the proper way or any other good practice to store and retrieve images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you store the URLs of the images and not the image itself, yes it's a recommended practice. You can store the entire URL, including `https://` or you can only store the ID of the image and then recreate the entire URL client side. So it's up to you to decide which solution works better for you.

This doesn't mean that you cannot store images, you can, but as a general rule, unless you're storing very very small icons, go ahead only with the URLs.